# ASP.NET javascript close page after timeout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I want show an information page after success db opartions. And after the info I want to close  each pages (information page and main page)

I wrote this in button oncommand event:

```
//but this code does not work
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>setTimeout('self.close();',3000);</script>");
```

at the same time, I want to show an information message. And then I want to close all, after three seconds.I hope I could explain :)

Thanks.

Comment: I think the browser is just blocking your close script. Put some debug message and check if your function is being executed.

Comment: Which browser you using? Sadly you are in browser specific territory.

Comment: In modern browsers script can't close windows that were not opened by that script. People don't like websites closing their browsers and I can totally agree to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox would only allow window.close(); and only if you opened the window with a script.

Refer: [window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.close)

> When this method is called, the referenced window is closed.
>
> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened
>   by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console:
>   Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Comment: Not on all browsers, it would work on older versions of IE. But There are better ways to present notifications to users. Floating divs, dialog windows(there are asp.net controls dedicated to do that), etc. These you can open/close very easily using scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem And It works with all browser.

here is code :

```
String MyScript = "";
MyScript += "<script language='javascript'>";
MyScript += "   window.open('', '_self', '');";
MyScript += "   top.window.close();";
MyScript += "</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "PopupClose", MyScript);
```